# django haystack and solr to search two classes in models

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

every one I am new to django haystack and solr ,,I now can use solr to search one models.However,when it comes two models I do not know how to do it?
here is my

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # The Dahl-specific manager.

    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year,
                                                 self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                                 self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                                 self.slug])


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

and if I use these search_indexes and post_text.txt I can search `Post`ok

> search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Post,Comment


class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().published.all()
```

> mysite/blog/templates/search/indexes/blog/post_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.tags.all|join:", " }}
{{ object.body }}
```

but,,I also have to search `Comment`

then I try these,they did not work

> search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Post,Comment


class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().published.all()


class Comment(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    comments = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='comments')

    def get_model(self):
        return Comment
```

> mysite/blog/templates/search/indexes/blog/comment_text.txt

```
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.email }}
{{ object.body }}
```

> views.py

.......

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
        return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                         'cd': cd,
                                                         'results': results,
                                                         'total_results': total_results})



    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,})
```

so should I add more views.py search and change search_indexes.py and post_text.txt ??

Comment: have you added comment_text.txt to templates?

Comment: no,,I did not ,,let me try it

Comment: I now added the mysite/blog/templates/search/indexes/blog/comment_text.txt  like above,,but after python manage.py rebuild_index still can not search,,I think I  have to adjust the views.py or somthings I missed?